# C# - How to use variable from dropdown in SQL query, and add column to second dropdown

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that pulls a column from a table, and then outputs to a dropdown list. I was using a long string of if else statements, but this does not accomplish my goal of being able to add another column to the table (which was added already) without adding another else clause to the lookup.

I have two dropdowns. The second one needs to change based on the first one's selection. Both drop downs are using separate tables so I can name the columns in the second table the same as a string in one of the columns of the first table. The items selected in the first dropdown have the same name as the columns in the second table for the second dropdown.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with SQL 2012.

Here is the code I have now, I have been trying parameters but I just can't quite get it to work, it is saying that the variable is not in the table. I know [systemItem] is not the best way to actually run it, I edited it so you can see what I am trying to do. The ORDER BY is in there to eliminate blank spaces from showing in the dropdown (which worked fine in the massive list of if else's). Thanks in advance guys!

```
                systemItem = firstDropdown.Text;
                secondDropdown.Items.Clear();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT [systemItem] FROM [table] WHERE [systemItem]IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [systemItem] ASC AND [systemItem] =@sItem", conn);
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@sItem";
                param.Value = systemItem;
                cm.Parameters.Add(param);
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        secondDropdown.Items.Add(dr[sItem]);
                        secondDropdown.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                conn.Close();
```

Edit: fixed name of one of the dropdowns to reflect what I am clearing.

Comment: You have a where clause and then an order by statement. But after you have "AND systemItem = @sItem". What is that last part supposed to be? Is that part of the where clause? You don't need to check for systemItem being not null if that is really part of the where clause because the equality check will eliminate NULL already.

Comment: That query worked fine without using variables, when I was using the if else statements and using the exact column name instead of variables. But I need it to work using the variables that way I can have my end users add to the table without me having to do it. The last part is supposed to be the variable for SQL. The ORDER BY was to sort alphabetically and eliminate blank spaces as some columns in the table have more in some rows than others.

Comment: The point I am making is that the query you posted here has syntax errors. You have an AND X = Y in your order by which won't work. Not sure what you mean by having your end users enters columns in your table. Are you saying you want the end user to be able to chose which column(s) to include in the order by? If you can help identify the requirement I can help you figure out a solution. As it stands right now it is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, so for this part of the project, basically, I need it to be able to query using a variable. That variable is whatever the selected text is in the first dropdown. The variable is also the same as the name of a column in the table. When it pulls up the table, it sorts it alphabetically (which is what the order by was for) and puts all of the rows of the column in the second dropdown.

There is a second form for the end users to add items to the table if necessary, using the "else if's" in my original post wouldn't allow for additions because I would have to add another "else if" manually

Comment: I am sure this is perfectly clear for you but for anybody else reading it is really fuzzy. I suspect you will need to use dynamic sql for what you are trying to do here but it is hard to say for sure. Also, I have no idea what you mean by your other post, I didn't go digging around trying to find your other post for information needed to answer this.